# AngularJS: resolve to return value of $resouce

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-resource

When I get the set point which is written on a JSON file using a $resource, how is it settled?
$promise of $resource don't have resolve function.

```
myApp.factory('prop', function($resource) {
  return {
    getSetting: function(key) {
      var res = $resource('setting.json').query();  // *1

      /* ? What is the processing here? */

      return res[key];
    }
  }
});
```

---

update add write

res is resource object.
res have $promise.
At the time *1, res is not settled.
I want to be settled in this function.
What kind of processing should I add?

---

Is it like that?

```
myApp.factory('prop', function($resource) {
  return {
    getSetting: function(key) {
      return $resource('setting.json').query().$promise.then(function(res) {
        return res[key];
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$resource return a resource object containing an attribute $promise. You can then on it.

```
var res = $resource('setting.json').$promise
    .then(
        function(result){//success handling},
        function(error){//error handling}
    );
```

Comment: Thx. but. By this method, i must implement then in a place to use this resouce object. It is not nice.